# JMeter - non GUI mode - how to get the app to run continously

Tags: loops, testing, count, jmeter

[image: Settings]I can get JMeter to run in non GUI mode but it stops after just running just one iteration. How do I get it to run continuously ? Loop Count is set to Infinite in this 5.5 JMeter version.

jmeter -n -t SocialGeneratorTrafficMOCKSQS.jmx -l C:\installs\How2Run_JMeter5_5_cmd_line\Results.csv -e -o C:\installs\How2Run_JMeter5_5_cmd_line\Report.csv

thank you

[image: JMeter]

[image: JMeter thread settings]

[image: CSV settings]

Comment: See your CSV configuration, probably mark as Stop

Comment: Yes believe you're right there. StopRun.txt file needs to be "No" in order for non GUI mode to run continuously ! Thx

Answer (score 0):

The reason for stopping the thread can be found in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

I can think of 2 possible reasons which might cause premature ending of your test:

1. [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) is configured to stop thread on EOF, make sure it's set up like at the image below:

   [image]
2. [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler is configured to stop either thread or test

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T,  I have looked at those settings - see attached images. App doesnt run continuously with these settings. What should I change them to ? I have tried Flow Control Action - Logical action on Thread settings of 'Pause' , 'Start next thread loop' and 'Go to next iteration of current loop' - but to no avail. thx